# Why dont display my images root in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, computer-vision, computer-science

This is the code I want to add Tkinter for read two image files from my directory but when the window display and try to apply the blending with track bar the image display is black, can you help me with this code, What am I doing wrong? Greetings

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import cv2 


root=Tk()
root.filename  =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Selec    t file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)

root.filename  =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Selec        t file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)

alphamax=100
window= 'Linear Blend'


def trackbar(value):
    alpha=value/alphamax
    beta=(1.0 - alphamax)
    dst = cv2.addWeighted(src1,alpha,src2,beta,0.0)
    cv2.imshow(window,dst)

src1 =cv2.imread(root.filename)
src2 =cv2.imread(root.filename)


cv2.namedWindow(window)
trackbar_name = 'Alpha x %d' % alphamax
cv2.createTrackbar(trackbar_name, window , 0, alphamax, trackbar)
 # Show some stuff
trackbar(0)
# Wait until user press some key
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: You should probably try using PIL instead of cv2

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL, like [this](https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-image/) example.